# Coffee flavored melted chocolate for drizzling over cookies?

Tags: coffee, melting-chocolate

I am making coffee flavored biscottis that I want to drizzle with coffee flavored melted chocolate, which should harden after. I have searched but without much luck. I was thinking of mixing a bit of instant coffee powder with some water to make a thick paste and then added to melted chocolate. Does this method sound ok and do I have to keep anything in mind when mixing the 2 ingredients together? I am a bit worried about adding liquid to melted chocolate. Maybe I should just mix instant coffee powder directly with melted chocolate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can get instant espresso powder (most big grocery stores in the US have it) that's what you want to use. NO WATER, small amounts of water will ruin chocolate, cause it to seize.

[image: 1]

Just sprinkle some powder in while the chocolate is melting. It will blend right in.

If you can't get espresso powder, you can use instant coffee, just be sure that it's a fine powder, or powder it yourself in a spice or coffee grinder.

To be sure that the instant coffee is fine enough, you might consider sifting it. Either powdered regular instant coffee or even the instant espresso might benefit from that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll powder instant coffee and maybe sift it before using it. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Divi It's a great idea to sift it. As a matter of fact, I'm going to add that to the answer.

Comment: Good point about seizing. You could also mix it with melted butter or warmed milk, if you need to dissolve it in something before mixing it with the chocolate. These are fat-based so won't cause the chocolate to seize in the way that water would.

Comment: Another thing you could do (depending on what texture you're going for) is just to use finely ground coffee beans instead of instant coffee.

Comment: @starsplusplus 4% fat cow's milk is nearly 90% water. Are you sure there's any real difference between adding milk and adding water?

Comment: I am not sure, no. I'm neither a chemist nor have I tried it personally, I've just seen it recommended. The fact that it functions as an [emulsion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk#Physical_and_chemical_properties_of_milk), may render the "90% water" fact less relevant (or it may not); perhaps someone more qualified can step in and educate us. Using cream would undoubtedly be better than milk, in any case.

Comment: @Jolenealaska: Thanks, it worked wonderfully. I melted the chocolate first before adding and frequently tasting small amounts of ground sifted instant coffee